# Como se sincronizan 2 hilos en python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola estoy haciendo el burbuja pero grafico:

entonces consta de 1 hilo y el tkinter //main loop

pero: el hilo del calculo va mas rapido que el hilo de tkinter entonces parpadea mucho que puedo hacer?

https://github.com/felipedelosh/Burbuja-segun-el-loko/blob/master/main.py

```
"""
FelipedelosH

6/20/2019

Se desea hacer un programa que dados 320 numeros aleatoreos de 0 a 400
los organice por medio de burbuja y muestre paso a paso con un slider que retarde
"""

from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from threading import *
from time import sleep

class GraphiBubbleShort():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pantalla = Tk()
        self.telaControl = Canvas(self.pantalla,width=640, height=80 ,bg="snow")
        self.telaGraficas = Canvas(self.pantalla,width=640, height=400 ,bg="white")
        self.btnPlay = Button(self.telaControl, text="PLAY", command=self.play)
        self.btnPausa = Button(self.telaControl, text="PAUSE", command=self.pause)
        self.lblIteracion = Label(self.telaControl, text="Iteracion: 0")

        """Variables"""
        self.vectorNumeros = [] # aqui se guardan los 640 numeros
        self.estoyRondando = False  # controla si el programa esta en ejecucion
        self.intSlider = 0.5

        self.hilo = Thread(target=self.run)
        """Preparativos para lanzar el programa"""
        # Se inicia el hilo
        self.hilo.start()
        # Se rellena el vector
        self.rellemarVectorNum()
        """Se muestra todo"""
        self.visualizarInterfaz()

    def visualizarInterfaz(self):
        self.pantalla.title("Burbuja by loko")
        self.pantalla.geometry("640x480")

        self.telaControl.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.btnPlay.place(x=10, y=20)
        self.btnPausa.place(x=60, y=20)
        self.lblIteracion.place(x=10, y=50)
        self.telaGraficas.place(x=0, y=80)

        """Se procede a graficar el vector"""
        self.graficarVector()
        self.pantalla.mainloop()

    def rellemarVectorNum(self):
        if not self.estoyRondando:
            self.vectorNumeros.clear()
            for i in range(320):
                self.vectorNumeros.append(randint(1, 400))

    def graficarVector(self):
        for i in range(0, len(self.vectorNumeros)):
            x0 = 1 + (2*i)
            self.telaGraficas.create_rectangle(x0, 0, x0+1, self.vectorNumeros[i], tags="vector")

    def play(self):
        self.pantalla.title("Burbuja by loko:PLAY")
        self.estoyRondando = True

    def pause(self):
        self.pantalla.title("Burbuja by loko:PAUSE")
        self.estoyRondando = False

    def run(self):
        contadori = 0
        contadorj = 0
        aux = 0
        Iteracion = 0
        while True:
            while self.estoyRondando and contadori < len(self.vectorNumeros):
                # procedo a instaciar j en lo que no esta ordenado
                contadorj = 0
                # procedo a borrar los numeros
                self.telaGraficas.delete("vector")
                while self.estoyRondando and contadorj < len(self.vectorNumeros)-(contadori+1):
                    if self.vectorNumeros[contadorj] < self.vectorNumeros[contadorj+1]:
                        aux = self.vectorNumeros[contadorj+1]
                        self.vectorNumeros[contadorj+1] = self.vectorNumeros[contadorj]
                        self.vectorNumeros[contadorj] = aux

                    if self.estoyRondando:
                        Iteracion = Iteracion + 1
                        self.lblIteracion['text'] = "Iteracion: "+str(Iteracion)
                        contadorj = contadorj + 1

                # se grafica el vector
                self.graficarVector()
                self.telaGraficas.update_idletasks()

                sleep(0.1)
                """Se incrementa i"""
                if self.estoyRondando:
                    contadori = contadori + 1



sw = GraphiBubbleShort()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que muestras tiene un problema importante, y es que la labor de repintado del canvas la estás haciendo desde el hilo de cómputo, en lugar de hacerlo desde el hilo de la interfaz.

En tu programa hay dos hilos separados:

- El hilo de la interfaz (también llamado hilo del GUI o hilo principal) que es el que existe al arrancar el programa, el que prepara toda la interfaz gráfica y se queda "enganchado" en la llamada a `self.pantalla.mainloop()` de la que nunca retorna. En esa función se queda en un bucle infinito procesando los eventos de la GUI, tales como pulsaciones de botones, cierres de la ventana, y otros.
- El hilo que creas en la llamada a `Thread()` y que arrancas en `self.hilo.start()`, que se ocupa de ejecutar la función `self.run()` de la que tampoco retorna nunca por ser un bucle infinito. En este bucle, cada cierto tiempo (cada 0.1 segundos tal como lo tienes), comprueba el estado de `self.estoyRondando` y si es `True`, realiza otra iteración de la burbuja para ordenar los números, y *repinta el canvas*, mientras que si es `False` no hace nada.

Si el usuario pulsa los botones Play o Pause, el hilo de GUI detecta ese evento desde `mainloop()` y lo despacha a la función `self.play()` o `self.pause()`, las cuales simplemente cambian el título de la ventana y el valor del booleano `self.estoyRondando`.

Este enfoque tiene dos problemas:

1. El hilo de cómputo siempre está ejecutándose, tanto si se ha pulsado Play como si no. La diferencia es que en un caso continúa ordenando números, y en el otro no hace nada, salvo dormir por otros 0.1 segundos. Esto no es lo más eficiente. Ese hilo debería estar bloqueado hasta que se pulse el botón Play (lo cual no sería difícil de implementar), y volver a bloquearse cuando se pulse Pause (lo que sería más difícil). No obstante ignoraremos este problema, ya que aunque el hilo está siempre en ejecución, no consumirá demasiada CPU gracias al `sleep()`.
2. El hilo de cómputo se ocupa también de actualizar el canvas. Esto es un error de diseño por dos razones: primero, el canvas se actualiza con la misma frecuencia que la lista de números, lo cual puede no ser lo más eficiente. Con un sleep de 0.1 la lista de números se estará actualizando 10 veces por segundo, pero si disminuyes el `sleep()` a 0.01, se actualizaría 100 veces por segundo. Es posible que el display no pueda seguirle el ritmo (implicaría 100FPS). Lo idóneo sería que el display se actualice con su propia frecuencia (por ejemplo 30FPS) independiente de la velocidad a que se procesa la lista de números en el otro hilo. Y la segunda razón, quizás aún más importante, es que **no se debe actualizar la GUI** desde ningún otro hilo que no sea el propio hilo de la GUI. Esto es así por la forma en que está diseñada Tk (y todas las bibliotecas de GUI). Violar esto puede llevar a resultados imprevisibles como los parpadeos que has observado.

Así pues, rediseñando la aplicación tendríamos que la misión de los dos hilos sería:

- Hilo de cómputo. Simplemente ir ordenando los números y no ocuparse de actualizar el Canvas.
- Hilo de GUI, cada cierto tiempo (por ejemplo, cada 30ms) tomar el estado de la lista de números y pintarlo en el canvas.

Usando este diseño tu código quedaría así:

```
"""
FelipedelosH

6/20/2019

Se desea hacer un programa que dados 320 numeros aleatoreos de 0 a 400
los organice por medio de burbuja y muestre paso a paso con un slider que retarde
"""

from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from threading import *
from time import sleep


class GraphiBubbleShort:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pantalla = Tk()
        self.telaControl = Canvas(self.pantalla, width=640, height=80, bg="snow")
        self.telaGraficas = Canvas(self.pantalla, width=640, height=400, bg="white")
        self.btnPlay = Button(self.telaControl, text="PLAY", command=self.play)
        self.btnPausa = Button(self.telaControl, text="PAUSE", command=self.pause)
        self.lblIteracion = Label(self.telaControl, text="Iteracion: 0")

        """Variables"""
        self.vectorNumeros = []  # aqui se guardan los 640 numeros
        self.estoyRondando = False  # controla si el programa esta en ejecucion
        self.intSlider = 0.5

        self.hilo = Thread(target=self.run)
        """Preparativos para lanzar el programa"""
        # Se inicia el hilo
        self.hilo.start()
        # Se rellena el vector
        self.rellemarVectorNum()
        """Se muestra todo"""
        self.visualizarInterfaz()


    def visualizarInterfaz(self):
        self.pantalla.title("Burbuja by loko")
        self.pantalla.geometry("640x480")

        self.telaControl.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.btnPlay.place(x=10, y=20)
        self.btnPausa.place(x=60, y=20)
        self.lblIteracion.place(x=10, y=50)
        self.telaGraficas.place(x=0, y=80)

        """Se procede a graficar el vector"""
        self.graficarVector()

        # Se añade un evento al bucle de eventos para que tan pronto
        # como arranque mainloop() lo procese. Ese evento consiste en 
        # invocar la función self.update_graphic lo antes posible (tras 0ms)
        self.pantalla.after(0, self.update_graphic)
        self.pantalla.mainloop()

    def rellemarVectorNum(self):
        if not self.estoyRondando:
            self.vectorNumeros.clear()
            for i in range(320):
                self.vectorNumeros.append(randint(1, 400))

    def update_graphic(self):
        """Esta función actualiza el estado de la gráfica cada 30ms"""

        # Solo la actualizamos si realmente está cambiando, para ahorrar CPU
        if self.estoyRondando:
            self.graficarVector()
            # Cambiamos también la etiqueta con el número de iteraciones
            self.lblIteracion["text"] = "Iteracion: " + str(self.Iteracion)
        self.pantalla.after(30, self.update_graphic)

    def graficarVector(self):
        # Borramos el canvas y lo repintamos
        self.telaGraficas.delete("vector")
        for i in range(0, len(self.vectorNumeros)):
            x0 = 1 + (2 * i)
            self.telaGraficas.create_rectangle(
                x0, 0, x0 + 1, self.vectorNumeros[i], tags="vector"
            )

    def play(self):
        self.pantalla.title("Burbuja by loko:PLAY")
        self.estoyRondando = True

    def pause(self):
        self.pantalla.title("Burbuja by loko:PAUSE")
        self.estoyRondando = False

    def run(self):
        contadori = 0
        contadorj = 0
        aux = 0
        # La variable Iteracion pasa a ser un atributo del objeto, para poder
        # compartirla con la función que actualiza la interfaz
        self.Iteracion = 0
        while True:
            while self.estoyRondando and contadori < len(self.vectorNumeros):
                # procedo a instaciar j en lo que no esta ordenado
                contadorj = 0
                while self.estoyRondando and contadorj < len(self.vectorNumeros) - (contadori + 1):
                    if (self.vectorNumeros[contadorj] < self.vectorNumeros[contadorj + 1]):
                        aux = self.vectorNumeros[contadorj + 1]
                        self.vectorNumeros[contadorj + 1] = self.vectorNumeros[contadorj]
                        self.vectorNumeros[contadorj] = aux

                    if self.estoyRondando:
                        self.Iteracion += 1
                        contadorj = contadorj + 1

                sleep(0.1)
                """Se incrementa i"""
                if self.estoyRondando:
                    contadori = contadori + 1


sw = GraphiBubbleShort()
```

Observa los comentarios para ver cómo he usado `pantalla.after()` para repintar el canvas (y el contador de iteraciones) cada 30ms desde el hilo de GUI.

Prueba a cambiar el `sleep(0.1)` por `sleep(0.01)` y verás cómo todo se ejecuta mucho más rápido (a diferencia de tu diseño original en el que no se apreciaba diferencia). 
[image: Captura pantalla]

Esto es debido a que ahora se ejecutan 100 iteraciones de la burbuja por segundo, pero la GUI sigue actualizándose sólo 30 veces por segundo. Cada vez que se actualice, lógicamente, mostrará un "frame"  que se diferenciará del anterior en varios números que han sido ordenados en ese tiempo. En tu diseño original ocurrirían 100 repintados por segundo, que ralentizarían el cómputo. Y si disminuyes el `sleep()` a 0.001, la ordenación será casi instantánea (mientras que en tu diseño original, forzando a repintar 1000 veces por segundo, toda la interfaz iba a "trompicones").

Comment: Amigo. acaso eres un Dios de la programacion? eres un genio.

Uffff todo me paso por la cabeza menos ese concepto de que cada X segundos se actualize la GUI... te confiezo que estaba haciedo un tetris pero por problemas de GUI e HILO lo abandone. me dejo sorprendido totalmente.

Comment: @andresfelipeHernandez Gracias, no es para tanto :-) Si en verdad la respuesta es lo que buscabas puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Amigo:  si tu supieras todos los problemas que he tenido por no conocer esa tecnica, pero una ultima pregunta?

por que: 
 self.pantalla.after(30, self.update_graphic) >> esta correcto
 self.pantalla.after(30, self.update_graphic()) >> Error de recursion?

que hay de diferente?

Comment: `self.pantalla.after()` necesita dos parámetros: el primero es un tiempo en milisegundos. El segundo es el **nombre** de una función (siendo más técnicos, diríamos la referencia a una función). Eso inserta en el bucle de eventos la petición de que esa función se ejecute, pero no ahora, sino ese número de mlisegundos más tarde. Al poner paréntesis tras el nombre de la función la estás invocando inmediatamente, lo cual ya sería un fallo, y lo que estarías pasando sería el valor retornado por esa función (en lugar de la función en sí), lo que sería otro fallo.

Comment: Además, si pones `self.update_graphic()` dentro de la propia función `update_graphic`, se estaría llamando a sí misma, inmediatamente, y como parte de la llamada llegaría a la línea en que vuelve a llamarse a sí misma, antes de haber podido retornar la primera vez. Y dentro de esa llamada, otra vez. Al final se llama una y otra vez sin llegar a retornar nunca, por lo que agota el número máximo permitido para llamadas anidadas (recursión). No ocurre lo mismo en la primera forma, pues cada 30ms se llama _y retorna_ antes de la siguiente llamada.